# Updating element on firebase binded array on vueJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this **Orders array** and on the inner div order, I check which status it has.

```
<div class="list-group" v-for="(order, key) in orders">
 <div class="order" v-if="checkOrderStatus(order.status)">
      <div class="dishes">
        <ul id="dishes" v-for="dish in order.dishes" >
          <li v-if="checkDishOnOrder(dish)">{{checkDishOnOrder(dish).quantity}} x {{checkDishOnOrder(dish).dishName}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="notInclude">
        <ul id="notInclude" v-for="dish in order.dishes" >
          <li v-if="checkForNotInclude(dish)">{{checkForNotInclude(dish)}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="table">
          <center><span id="table">{{order.tableID}}</span></center>
      </div>
      <div class="hour">
          <center><span id="hour">{{order.hour}}</span></center>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
          <center><button type="button" id="status" :class="{'doingOrder' : order.status == 'Pedido pronto', 'orderDone' : order.status == 'Pronto para entrega'}" @click="changeStatus(order)">{{order.status}}</button></center>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

On the `beforeCreate:` I binded this array with a firebase ref:

```
this.$bindAsArray('orders', database.ref('orders/' + user.uid).orderByChild('hourOrder'))
```

The problem is, every time I change a order status the last element of the array changes together and it should not happen.

Here is my `checkOrderStatus:` function:

```
checkOrderStatus: function(orderStatus) {
      if(this.orderType == 'Em andamento') {
        if(orderStatus != "Pronto para entrega") {
          return true
        }
      } else if (this.orderType == 'Pedidos feitos') {
        if(orderStatus == "Pronto para entrega") {
          return true
        }
      }

    },
```

Here is `changeStatus:` function:

```
changeStatus: function(order) {
      var that = this;
      var database = Firebase.database();
      var loggedUser = Firebase.auth().currentUser;

      if (order.status == 'Em andamento') {
        order.status = 'Pedido pronto';

        var orderKey = order['.key'];
        delete order['.key'];

        var updates = {};
        updates['orders/' + loggedUser.uid + '/'+ orderKey] = order;

        database.ref().update(updates).then(function() {
          console.log('order Updated');

        })
      }
      else if(order.status == 'Pedido pronto') {
        order.status = 'Pronto para entrega';

        var orderKey = order['.key'];
        delete order['.key'];

        var updates = {};
        updates['orders/' + loggedUser.uid + '/'+ orderKey] = order;

        database.ref().update(updates).then(function() {
          console.log('order Updated');

        })
      }

    },
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you change the order status, since that is apparently where the problem is?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to avoid this behavior using computed properties:

```
computed: {
  fixedOrders() {
    var database = Firebase.database();
    this.$bindAsArray('orders', database.ref('orders/' + this.userID).orderByChild('hourOrder'))
    return this.orders
  },
}
```

I've binded the array again on a computed property, so that way it always have the right values for orders.

I'm just concerned about the performance loss because I'm biding the orders array again every time it changes.